# Flex 4 - How to align FormItem Label and TextInput?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have the **FormItem** with **Label** and **TextInput** controls.

Sample code

```
    <s:FormItem id="mobileLabel" label="Mobile Number">
        <s:TextInput id="mobileInput"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem id="emailLabel" label="Email ID" required="true">
        <s:HGroup>
            <s:TextInput id="emailInput"/>
            <s:Label id="bindingLabel" text="@xyz.com"/>
        </s:HGroup> 
    </s:FormItem>
```

Output like this:

[image]

How to align the label text as bottom of the label?
like this

[image]

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361699/flex-formitem-label-aligment-oddity/13362296#13362296

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the HGroup's proberty verticalAlign. Then your HGroup statement will look like:

```
<s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle">
  <s:TextInput id="emailInput"/>
  <s:Label id="bindingLabel" text="@xyz.com"/>
</s:HGroup>
```